# Как передать функции словарь с переменными?

Tags: python

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как передать функции словарь с переменными и их значениями ? Хочу избавится от большого кол -ва аргументов в функции.
Создал отдельный модуль main для хранения всех значений переменных:

```
class AllVarsClass:
    def putVarsToDict(self):
        MatrixFileString = 'd:\Matrix.xlsx'
        MatrixFileHeaderStart = 'A1'
        MatrixFileHeaderEnd = 'I2'
        MatrixFileIDProdStart = 'A3'
        MatrixFileIDProdEnd = 'A188'
        MatrixFileNameProdStart = 'I3'
        MatrixFileNameProdEnd = 'I188'
        VarsDict = {}
        for variable in ["MatrixFileString", "MatrixFileHeaderStart", "MatrixFileHeaderEnd",
                         "MatrixFileIDProdStart", "MatrixFileIDProdEnd", 
                         "MatrixFileNameProdStart", "MatrixFileNameProdEnd"]:
            VarsDict[variable] = eval(variable)
        return VarsDict
```

Создал еще один модуль matrix с классом и методом который создает объект main и заливает словарь в VarsDict:

```
import main
class MatrixClass:
     def makeMatrixFile(self):  
        Obj = main.AllVarsClass()
        VarsDict = {}
        VarsDict = Obj.putVarsToDict()
        dirName = os.path.dirname(VarsDict[MatrixFileString]) + '\\'
```

При вызове метода makeMatrixFile() вылетает ошибка:
"dirName = os.path.dirname(VarsDict[MatrixFileString]) + '\'
NameError: name 'MatrixFileString' is not defined"

Comment: а что за переменная `MatrixFileString`? или вам `VarsDict['MatrixFileString']` надо использовать?

Comment: а почему вы не делает просто словарь в putVarsToDict(), а используете какую-то кривую конструкицю в виде дополнительных переменных, цикла и eval?

Answer (score 1):

`MatrixFileString` - переменная, которая у вас существует только в функции `putVarsToDict()` класса `AllVarsClass`. `"MatrixFileString"` - ключ словаря, который возвращает эта функция. Это разные вещи и путать их нельзя. Вам нужно использовать `VarsDict["MatrixFileString"]`.

Comment: Спасибо, теперь все работает!

Answer (score 1):

в подобных случаях иногда кроме словаря удобно использовать [namedtuple](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#namedtuple-factory-function-for-tuples-with-named-fields). для вашего примера это будет выглядеть так:

```
from collections import namedtuple

AllVars = namedtuple('AllVars','MatrixFileString MatrixFileHeaderStart MatrixFileHeaderEnd MatrixFileIDProdStart MatrixFileIDProdEnd MatrixFileNameProdStart MatrixFileNameProdEnd')
all_vars = AllVars('d:\Matrix.xlsx','A1','I2','A3','A188','I3','I188')
```

теперь в all_vars лежат все "переменные":

```
print(all_vars)
# AllVars(MatrixFileString='d:\\Matrix.xlsx', MatrixFileHeaderStart='A1', MatrixFileHeaderEnd='I2', MatrixFileIDProdStart='A3', MatrixFileIDProdEnd='A188', MatrixFileNameProdStart='I3', MatrixFileNameProdEnd='I188')
```

обращаемся к "переменным" как к атрибутам:

```
all_vars.MatrixFileString  # 'd:\\Matrix.xlsx'
```